# Progress bar fill with form inputs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uiprogressbar

I'm trying to get this progress bar working, but i keep getting wrong results. The problem is when i fill in the first input (whatever input), then i get 60% in stead of the percentage of the specified input.

```
$(function () {
$("#progressbar").progressbar({
  value: 0
});

$("#profil input").change(function () {
    var pbVal = 0;
    if ($("#name").val().length > 0) pbVal += 10;
    if ($("#prenoun").val().length > 0) pbVal += 10;
    if ($("#birthday").val().length > 0) pbVal += 10;
    if ($("#telephone").val().length > 0) pbVal += 10;
    if ($("#region").val().length > 0) pbVal += 10;
    if ($("#ville").val().length > 0) pbVal += 10;
    if ($("#etablissement").val().length > 0) pbVal += 10;
    if ($("#matiere").val().length > 0) pbVal += 10;
    if ($("#etablistud").val().length > 0) pbVal += 10;
    if ($("#niveau").val().length > 0) pbVal += 10;
    if ($("#branche").val().length > 0) pbVal += 10;
    $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value", pbVal);
    return false;
});
```

});

Any solution please ? here it is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fcwgvoLa)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.val() for your dropdowns is returning 'default' so the length will be greater than 0. Try changing it to this instead

```
if ($("#name").val().length > 0) pbVal += 10;
if ($("#prenoun").val().length > 0) pbVal += 10;
if ($("#birthday").val().length > 0) pbVal += 10;
if ($("#telephone").val().length > 0) pbVal += 10;
if ($("#region").val() != 'default') pbVal += 10;
if ($("#ville").val() != 'default') pbVal += 10;
if ($("#etablissement").val().length > 0) pbVal += 10;
if ($("#matiere").val().length > 0) pbVal += 10;
if ($("#etablistud").val() != 'default') pbVal += 10;
if ($("#niveau").val() != 'default') pbVal += 10;
if ($("#branche").val() != 'default') pbVal += 10;
```

Comment: Thanks @cspete, its working fine now. i also forgot to target selects, better use .val() than .length. Thanks again